# How to update table columns after passed array items in controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

How to update table columns after send data from view to controller, I send 3 items in array: idemployee, idtip,bool.In my table i have columns idmployee,idtip,active(True,False).

This is my controller with passed ajax data: items

```
public ActionResult DataStates(IEnumerable<employeesnadtips> items)
```

When I debug it succesfully showed me a result but how to update column by column when i pass values in array and one defined parameter called `items`.

[image: items result]

```
(".chktip").each(function (index, item) {
                var TestViewModel = {};
                TestViewModel.idtip= $(this).attr("idtip");
                TestViewModel.idmployee = $('.idmployee').val();
                TestViewModel.active= $(this).prop('checked');
                EmpEls.push(TestViewModel);
            });

            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: UrlSettingsDocument.TipsEmp, 
                data: { items: EmpEls},  
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data)
                },
                error: function (response) {
                    console.log(response.responseText);
                }
            });
```

Comment: Where is the `active` property? I didn't see you add that in `TestViewModel`.

Comment: @mj1313 It's ok now i just rename `TestViewModel.isChecked` to `active`, and its ok now.